# QGIS feature rendering order and archeological stratigraphy

Tags: qgis, symbology, rendering

For archeology purposes, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with code using control rendering order option in QGIS:

On a polygon layer I have multiple columns containg the stratigraphic relations between my polygons. I want to set the rendering order of each single polygon according to its relation with the other that are intersecting.

My features table contains this data :

```
Feature n° above
1001       1002;4785;9687
1002       4785;7003;5874
```

it means than polygon 1001 should be drawn above the following polygons : 1002;4785;9687
and my polygon 1002 should be drawn above 4785;7003; and so on.

is this technically feasible?

Comment: in the Layer Properties and in the Symbology tab there is an option – Control feature rendering order. you can use one ore more columns and expressions to achieve this. keep in mind, that you can build your own python functions with the expression builder, so there are some options to achieve your goal.

Comment: yeah i just don't understand how the control feature rendering works. Meaning that I don't know how to construct the code if I don't know what type of results i'm expected to obtain for this thing to work.